# How can I change the number of dimensions for output of a TFlite model?

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite, google-mlkit

I'm using MLKit by Google for an Android App to make object detection.
I know there are some TFlite models compatible with MLKit but when I use others models most of time I have this error:

```
 com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.mlkit.common.MlKitException: Failed to initialize detector. Unexpected number of dimensions for output index 0: got 3D, expected either 2D (BxN with B=1) or 4D (BxHxWxN with B=1, W=1, H=1).
```

I wonder if is possible (and **how to**) manipulate the Input/Output (for some models the problem is the input for other the output) to satisfy the requirements for MLKit here: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/custom-models#model-compatibility

I'm trying to fit a square pig inside a round hole?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to fit the square pig[sic] inside a round hole - it will be painful for the square pig.  You can just pick a round pig, a model that is compatible with ML Kit, here:

https://tfhub.dev/ml-kit